# Codeigniter-session value and passed argument to controller method

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using Codeigniter 3 framework and encounter a problem.
In my app, there is 2 controller:
**Main** and **User**.
In **Main** controller, there are two methods, **method1** (with no parameter) and **method2** (with one parameter), which both load own view, but there is an identical form in their view that will be submitted to **User** controller method. In both method1 and method2, I generate a random number and store in $data['random'], also in a session variable (for future checking):
$data['random'] = generate_random();
$this->session->set_userdata('random', $data['random']);
$data['random'] in both method is set in form input and then submitted.
The problem is: when I retrieve data (in **User** controller) which is submitted from **method1**, and compare with session value, they are equal. **BUT** this scenario for **method2** is different. the submitted value is not equal to session value!!!
The only difference between methods is: method2 accept parameters and method1, no.
NOTE: when I assign a fixed number (instead of generate random) to $data['random'], the result of both methods are equal.

**Edited:** added codes

The **Main** controller methods:

```
public function method1(){
 //other data setting and...

 $data['random'] = generate_random();
 $this->session->set_userdata('random', $data['random']);

 $this->load->view('view_folder/first', $data);
}

public function method2($param){
 //other data setting and...

 $data['random'] = generate_random();
 $this->session->set_userdata('random', $data['random']);

 $this->load->view('view_folder/second', $data);
}
```

The **User** controller method:

```
public function check(){
 echo $this->input->post() . '<br>';
 echo $this->session->userdata('random');
 exit();
 //other...
}
```

In view files, an identical form is part of view code. As I said, $data['random'] will be set as input value in form and this will be submitted. Another thing, in **first** view file, there some items which link to **method2**:

```
<!-- other -->
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>main/method2/3">some item</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>main/method2/some_var">some item</a>
<!-- other -->
```

I check code carefully, test different cases, I think this problem related to passed argument to method2. I mean, the passed parameter create problem. But I have no idea and logical reason!

Comment: Can you display more code ? It's so verbose I get lost at the middle of it :/

Comment: By how you described, the random numbers should equal. I'd assume that there must be an error in your code. Be sure that the session variable is being set in method 2, and that right variable is being passed in your hidden input. Post more code and we can help you more.